# Angular2 system.js app on ec2 how to deploy - node-pre-gyp ERR

Tags: angular

I developed a anuglar2 app using the official startpack usijng system.js on a mac.  I then uploaded to ec2 - how do I even start fixing the below?

```
npm install

> fsevents@1.0.14 install /var/qta-angular2/node_modules/fsevents
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

node-pre-gyp ERR! Tried to download: https://fsevents-binaries.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1.0.14/fse-v1.0.14-node-v46-linux-x64.tar.gz 
node-pre-gyp ERR! Pre-built binaries not found for fsevents@1.0.14 and node@4.5.0 (node-v46 ABI) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
gyp ERR! clean error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, rmdir 'build'
gyp ERR! stack     at Error (native)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-87-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "clean"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/qta-angular2/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/qta-angular2/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:829:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 3.13.0-87-generic
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/var/qta-angular2/node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /var/qta-angular2/node_modules/fsevents
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v4.5.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.6.29
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok 
Failed to execute '/usr/bin/nodejs /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js clean' (1)

npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-87-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! fsevents@1.0.14 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fsevents@1.0.14 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the fsevents package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs fsevents
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls fsevents
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/qta-angular2/npm-debug.log
root@angular2-qta-aws-development-east-10ywylp:/var/qta-angular2#
```